# SQL COUNT values modified by HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the best clients in a MySQL database by counting the number of commands per client and selecting the clients whose command count is larger or equal than all the command counts with the following query :

```
SELECT client.name, COUNT(*) AS CmdCount
FROM client NATURAL JOIN command
GROUP BY command.idClient
HAVING CmdCount >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM command
GROUP BY command.idClient)
```

This doesn't work and the CmdCount values are wrong : the values are different than the ones obtained when I remove the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT client.name, COUNT(*) AS CmdCount
FROM client NATURAL JOIN command
GROUP BY command.idClient
```

The subquery returns the expected results, so the problem comes from assembling both requests. The following request works as well :

```
SELECT client.name, COUNT(*) AS CmdCount
FROM client NATURAL JOIN command
GROUP BY command.idClient
HAVING CmdCount >= 76
```

I would like to know why the faulty request fails as well as if there is a better approach to solve this problem.

Edit (in reply to the comments) :
this is a simplified version of the request to keep the focus on the problem, and this is not used in a real world application. The problem is the same if I use INNER JOIN / ON. As far as the choice of name for grouping, I tend to think that there is a risk in grouping different clients having the same name (hence the choice of idClient). To keep the focus on the behavior I am trying to understand I simplified the query, and there is probably something I am missing but it doesn't behave as I expect :

```
SELECT idClient, COUNT(*) AS CmdCount
FROM command
GROUP BY idClient
HAVING CmdCount >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM command
GROUP BY idClient)
```

Comment: You should not use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is a bug waiting to happen.  I strongly recommend either `USING` or `ON`.

Comment: You select client.name, but group by command.idClient. How come? (Invalid according to the ANSI SQL standard, and most dbms products...)

Comment: Mixing `SELECT client.name` and `GROUP BY command.idClient` is a dangerous choice.  You should really `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the same thing *(the `name` in your case)* just in case two `idClient` have the same `name`...  *(Although legal syntax in MySQL, and does have its uses, using it in the way you have done would be considered a bug in most quality reviews I've been a part of.)*